# Metronic's loading older version in browser during run time

Tags: node-modules, metronic

Im using html version of metronics. I see  some of the assets are loaded dynamically during run time in browser.

I need to update Handlerbar version.. but even we update the version in local configurations/bundle.js, metronics is pulling  older version of metronics. we can see the files loaded in sources tab in browser

can you some one guide. how to get updated handlebar version during runtime load